# How to define the nuclear norm of a tensor?

Tags: normed-spaces, tensors, svd, nuclear-norm

As we know, the nuclear norm of a matrix $X$ is defined as follows

$$\|X\|_{*} = \sum \sigma_{i}$$

where $\sigma_{i}$ is the $i$-th singular value of $X$. How to define the nuclear norm of a **tensor** $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1773v1.pdf